# Circular list in Graphviz? or how to bend the edge

Tags: graphviz

I had been trying to do what I thought was a simple thing in Graphviz, something like this:

[image] (taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394432/how-to-draw-circular-linked-list)

And I am trying to do something similar with Graphviz, this is how it looks right now:

[image]

I read the documentation and tried already with neato and circo diagrams and no success.... How can I achieve bending the edge in the way I need? I now I could try using a coordinate, like `p3:e -> p1:w` but that will remove the start point from the middle of the record.

This is my code so far:

```
digraph {
  node[shape=record];
  graph[pencolor=transparent];
  rankdir=LR;
  p1[label="{<data> 12|<next>}"];
  p2[label="{<data> 99|<next>}"];
  p3[label="{<data> 37|<next>}"];

  edge[tailclip=false,arrowtail=dot,dir=both];

  p1:next:c -> p2:data;
  p2:next:c -> p3:data;
  p3:next:c -> p1:data[constraint=false];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need some helper nodes (p0 and p4)

```
digraph {
  node[shape=record];
  graph[pencolor=transparent];
  rankdir=LR;
  p1[label="{<data> 12|<next>}"];
  p2[label="{<data> 99|<next>}"];
  p3[label="{<data> 37|<next>}"];

  edge[tailclip=false,arrowtail=dot,dir=both];

  {node[shape=point height=0] p0 p4} // make p0 and p4 to small to see
  p0:n -> p1[arrowtail=none]
  p0:s -> p4:s[dir=none] // add edge with no arrow to make it look like one long edge, also make p0 the tail so we don't have a recursition that may course dot to rearange the nodes
  p1:next:c -> p2:data;
  p2:next:c -> p3:data;
  //p3:next:c -> p1:data[constraint=false];
  p3:next:c -> p4:n[arrowhead=none]
}
```

[image]

You can probably do the cross in the tail by using html table label and adding an image to one of the cells

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do helper nodes work? I was looking all around about this without any success :(

Comment: @cprieto well it's not a GraphViz concept just ordinary nodes that are configure to not show du to ther small side, some peopel will refer to them as scarfolding, if you remove 'height=0' it is more obvious what is going on. I sugest you play around with my example on viz-js.com